# Access files on different drive with html <audio>

Tags: php, html, audio

I want to play an audio file on html that is positioned on another drive on my computer. I have a very big music library and I can't really copy it on my www directory so I use an extrenal hard drive. If I use:

```
<audio controls src="F:/Music/<?php echo $filePath . "/"; ?>
```

it doesn't work. There is a php script that feeds the $filePath with the file names and paths for every mp3 and m4a file on the F:/Music/ directory. How can I use the audio files on another HDD to play them on html audio tag?

Comment: I don't know well windows, but did you try to put a shortcut (for `F:\Music\\`) in your www directory?